# Android: How to get a list of apps or call main app menu/launcher from my app?

Tags: android

I want the user to be able to open another app of his choice from my app.  I want the experience to be the same (or similar) to hitting that little button with six dots on the home screen. (What is that screen called to which that the button takes the user?)

Can I send an intent to this menu view? If so, what is it called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the same (or similar) to hitting that little button with six dots on the home screen

Only some home screens have a button fitting that description. Different home screens might use other icons for this.

> What is that screen called to which that the button takes the user?

That is variously referred to as the launcher or the app drawer.

> Can I send an intent to this menu view?

Not in general. It is conceivable that some home screen implementations expose something that can trigger opening that, but it would vary by home screen.

You are welcome to make your own launcher, by using `PackageManager` to find all the activities that support the `MAIN`/`LAUNCHER` `<intent-filter>`. [This sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Introspection/Launchalot) demonstrates how to do this.